# Brute force attack test on password for file

Tags: perl, passwords, combinations, system-calls, brute-force

I'm trying to create a brute force that will work on a specific files password.

I'm not sure how to get this code to work. This is what I have so far. This code produces the correct possible combinations for the password but I am not sure how to implement this into a brute force attack.

```
my @alpha = qw(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z);
my $password = @alpha[1];
my @combo = ();

for my $one(@alpha){
for my $two(@alpha){
for my $three(@alpha){
for my $four(@alpha){ push @combo, "$one$two$three$four\n"} }}
```

I assume ill need to use this command somewhere and `secret_file_brute.zip` is the file I'm using to test on.

I'm not sure how to declare the `$password` variable and how to enter my generated combinations from above one by one where the `$password` command is until the passwords is a match.

```
$returnVal = system("unzip -qq -o -P $password
secret_file_brute.zip > /dev/null 2>&1");
```

Comment: Aside: You probably don't want the `\n` inside the `@combo` elements - it looks like you put it there to see a print out (and `join` would have been better way to achieve that)

Comment: Are you trying to generate all possible combination of passwords (say eight characters long) that consist of the 26 latin alphabet letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brute force password cracking is very inefficient, so not really useful except as proof of concept. 
You've a 4 character alphabetical password, which is a fairly trivial case.

First off - you can write:

```
my @alpha =( "a".."z" );
```

generating the words as you're doing will work, but you'll be inserting a linefeed, which means whatever `system` command you're running won't work.

You also might find making the attempt as you go will improve your speed, not least because you can use multiprocessing trivially for this sort of operation.

Also - you can trap the return code for `system` to see when you succeed. Capturing the *text* output of system won't help - you need to inspect `$?` - see: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html

Something like this maybe?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Parallel::ForkManager;

my $parallel = 8;

my @alpha = ( "a" .. "z" );

my $manager = Parallel::ForkManager->new($parallel);

my $parent_pid = $$; 

for my $one (@alpha) {
    for my $two (@alpha) {
        for my $three (@alpha) {
            for my $four (@alpha) {
                $manager->start and next;
                system(
                    "unzip -qq -o -P $one$two$three$four secret_file_brute.zip > /dev/null 2>&1"
                );
                if ( not $? ) {
                      print "Password was $one$two$three$four\n";
                      kill $parent_pid;
                }

                $manager->finish;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great but is there a way to do this without Parallel::Forkmanger or any other module?

Comment: Yes. Comment out those lines. Or just read up on the fork() built in. But I will point out that one of the big advantages of Perl is the code reuse.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to generate all possible combination of passwords with the 26 latin characters. Right? Why not use the *increment* operator?

```
$password = "a";
for (;;) {
    say "$password";
    $password++;
}
```

`$password` will go from `a` to `z`, then from `aa` to `zz`, then from `aaa` to `zzz`, etc. Thus generating each and every possible combination of passwords from the 26 latin alphabetic characters.

If you're only interested in four character combinations:

```
$password = "aaaa";
while ( length $password < 5 ) {
    say "$password";
    $password++;
}
```