# Perl - Trouble with my unzip system call for zip file crack

Tags: perl, dictionary, scripting

I am a junior currently taking a scripting languages class that is suppose to spit us out with intermediate level bash, perl, and python in one semester. Since this class is accelerated, we speed through topics quickly and our professor endorses using forums to supplement our learning if we have questions.

I am currently working on our first assignment. The requirement is to create a very simple dictionary attack using a provided wordlist "linux.words" and a basic bruteforce attack. The bruteforce needs to compensate for any combination of 4 letter strings.

I have used print statements to check if my logic is sound, and it seems it is. If you have any suggestions on how to improve my logic, I am here to learn and I am all ears.

This is on Ubuntu v12.04 in case that is relevant.

I have tried replacing the scalar within the call with a straight word like unicorn and it runs fine, obviously is the wrong password, and it returns correctly. I have done this both in terminal and in the script itself. My professor has looked over this for a good 15 minutes he could spare, before referring me to forum, and said it looked good. He suspected that since I wrote the code using Notepad++ there might be hidden characters. I rewrote the code straight in the terminal using vim and it gave the same errors above. The code pasted is below is from vim.

My actual issue is that my system call is giving me problems. It returns the help function for unzip showing usages and other help material.

Here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

#Prototypes
sub brute();
sub dict();
sub AddSlashes($);

### ADD SLASHES ###

sub AddSlashes($)
{

    my $text = shift;
    $text =~ s/\\/\\\\/g;
    $text =~ s/'/\\'/g;
    $text =~ s/"/\\"/g;
    $text =~ s/\\0/\\\\0/g;
    return $text;

}

### BRUTEFORCE ATTACK ###
sub brute()
{

    print "Bruteforce Attack...\n";
    print "Press any key to continue.\n";
    if (<>)
    {

        #INCEPTION START
        my @larr1 = ('a'..'z'); #LEVEL 1 +
        foreach (@larr1)
        {
        my $layer1 = $_; #LEVEL 1 -

            my @larr2 = ('a'..'z'); #LEVEL 2 +
            foreach (@larr2)
            {
            my $layer2 = $_; # LEVEL 2 -

                my@larr3 = ('a'..'z'); #LEVEL 3 +
                foreach (@larr3)
                {
                my $layer3 = $_; #LEVEL 3 -

                    my@larr4 = ('a'..'z'); #LEVEL 4 +
                    foreach (@larr4)
                    {
                    my $layer4 = $_;
                    my $pass = ("$layer1$layer2$layer3$layer4"); 
                    print ($pass); #LEVEL 4 -
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}

### DICTIONARY ATTACK ###
sub dict()
{

    print "Dictionary Attack...\n"; #Prompt User
    print "Provide wordlist: ";
    my $uInput = "";
    chomp($uInput = <>); #User provides wordlist
    (open IN, $uInput) #Bring in wordlist
        or die "Cannot open $uInput, $!"; #If we cannot open file, alert

    my @dict = <IN>; #Throw the wordlist into an array

    foreach (@dict)
    {

        print $_; #Debug, shows what word we are on
        #next; #Debug
        my $pass = AddSlashes($_); #To store the $_ value for later use

        #Check pass call
        my $status = system("unzip -qq -o -P $pass secret_file_dict.zip > /dev/null 2>&1"); #Return unzip system call set to var

        #Catch the correct password
        if ($status == 0)
        {

            print ("Return of unzip is ", $status, " and pass is ", $pass, "\n"); #Print out value of return as well as pass
            last;

        }

    }
}
### MAIN ###
dict();


exit (0);
```

Here is my error

```
See "unzip -hh" or unzip.txt for more help.  Examples:
  unzip data1 -x joe   => extract all files except joe from zipfile data1.zip
  unzip -p foo | more  => send contents of foo.zip via pipe into program more
  unzip -fo foo ReadMe => quietly replace existing ReadMe if archive file newer
aerify
UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Debian. Original by Info-ZIP.

Usage: unzip [-Z] [-opts[modifiers]] file[.zip] [list] [-x xlist] [-d exdir]
  Default action is to extract files in list, except those in xlist, to exdir;
  file[.zip] may be a wildcard.  -Z => ZipInfo mode ("unzip -Z" for usage).

  -p  extract files to pipe, no messages     -l  list files (short format)
  -f  freshen existing files, create none    -t  test compressed archive data
  -u  update files, create if necessary      -z  display archive comment only
  -v  list verbosely/show version info       -T  timestamp archive to latest
  -x  exclude files that follow (in xlist)   -d  extract files into exdir
modifiers:
  -n  never overwrite existing files         -q  quiet mode (-qq => quieter)
  -o  overwrite files WITHOUT prompting      -a  auto-convert any text files
  -j  junk paths (do not make directories)   -aa treat ALL files as text
  -U  use escapes for all non-ASCII Unicode  -UU ignore any Unicode fields
  -C  match filenames case-insensitively     -L  make (some) names lowercase
  -X  restore UID/GID info                   -V  retain VMS version numbers
  -K  keep setuid/setgid/tacky permissions   -M  pipe through "more" pager
  -O CHARSET  specify a character encoding for DOS, Windows and OS/2 archives
  -I CHARSET  specify a character encoding for UNIX and other archives

See "unzip -hh" or unzip.txt for more help.  Examples:
  unzip data1 -x joe   => extract all files except joe from zipfile data1.zip
  unzip -p foo | more  => send contents of foo.zip via pipe into program more
  unzip -fo foo ReadMe => quietly replace existing ReadMe if archive file newer
aerifying
```

It is obviously not complete. In the main I will switch the brute(); for dict(); as needed to test. Once I get the system call working I will throw that into the brute section.

If you need me to elaborate more on my issue, please let me know. I am focused here on learning, so please add idiot proof comments to any thing you respond to me with.

Comment: This probably means that there's something wrong in the way you're using `unzip` in your script.  Have you tried entering the unzip command manually?  Does it work?

Comment: I have tried replacing the scalar with just a random word (obviously wrong password) like unicorn and it runs properly and gives me back the wrong password. I have done this both in the terminal AND in the code itself. It seems that it is something specifically with using a scalar in the system call or with the unzip call.

Comment: Are these the same homework problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894589/brute-force-attack-test-on-password-for-file

Comment: I would suggest generating the command first, printing the contents, then executing. Something like this: `my $unzip_command = "unzip -qq -o -P $pass secret_file_dict.zip > /dev/null 2>&1"; print  $unzip_command . "\n"; system( $unzip_command ); `

Comment: I believe that the problem is that you're using `-P` (capital p) vs. `-p` (lower case p). Unzip only recognizes the lower case version, and is throwing an error on the upper case option.

Comment: @Barton, that is not correct. Try `unzip -hh | grep password`.

Comment: @BartonChittenden , -p is running through the list now. Though every 300th or so item throws the same error before continuing on like normal. Why would this be? Also according to http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_unzip.htm -P capital is password though? Why is -p lowercase working? Also, could you explain the 2nd line you suggested to me? Thank for help!!

Comment: @SinanÜnür I checked the grepped usage. It is confusing. is it unzip $password p filename? The usage I grepped shows -P p Usepassword p to decrypt. It's very confusing =/

Comment: @Sobrique Yes same question from a classmate also. His issue was a little different than mine, though thanks for linking. The suggestions on his thread will help me streamline my scripts speed once I get it working.

Comment: That's fine. Thought it looked similar, was slightly confused. Not a problem for a well asked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: DO NOT USE PERL'S PROTOTYPES. They don't do what you or your professor might wish they do.

Second: Don't write homebrew escaping routines such as `AddSlashes`. Perl has [quotemeta](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#quotemeta). Use it.

Your problem is not with the specific programming language. How much time your professor has spent on your problem, how many classes you take are irrelevant to the problem. Focus on the actual problem, not all the extraneous "stuff".

Such as, *what is the point of `sub brute`?* You are not calling it in this script, it is not relevant to your problem, so don't post it. Narrow down your problem to the smallest relevant piece.

Don't prompt for the wordlist file in the body of `dict`. Separate the functionality into bite sized chunks so in each context you can focus on the problem at hand. Your `dict_attack` subroutine should expect to receive either a filehandle or a reference to an array of words. To keep memory footprint low, we'll assume it's a filehandle (so you don't have to keep the entire wordlist in memory).

So, your `main` looks like:

```
sub main {
    # obtain name of wordlist file
    # open wordlist file
    # if success, call dict_attack with filehandle
    # dict_attack returns password on success
}
```

Now, you can focus on `dict_attack`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

main();

sub dict_attack {
    my $dict_fh = shift;

    while (my $word = <$dict_fh>) {
        $word =~ s/\A\s+//;
        $word =~ s/\s+\z//;

        print "Trying $word\n";

        my $pass = quotemeta( $word );
        my $cmd = "unzip -qq -o -P $pass test.zip";
        my $status = system $cmd;
        if ($status == 0) {
            return $word;
        }
    }

    return;
}

sub main {
    my $words = join("\n", qw(one two three four five));
    open my $fh, '<', \$words or die $!;
    if (my $pass = dict_attack($fh)) {
        print "Password is '$pass'\n";
    }
    else {
        print "Not found\n";
    }
    return;
}
```

Output:

```
C:\...> perl y.pl
Trying one
Trying two
Trying three
Trying four
Trying five
Password is 'five'
```

Comment: I had trouble getting your section of code to work when I made changes for it to prompt and accept an outside zip file, however mine worked flawlessly the minute I used quotemeta and matched the scalar to a pattern. Thanks a ton @SinanUnur